# OpenRefine: 'Fill Up' replacing values along one column

Tags: openrefine, google-refine, grel

I have following table

```
╔════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ record ║ Brand  ║ Model  ║ Spec   ║
╠════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║   1    ║   X    ║ null   ║ 1      ║
║        ║   X    ║ DF     ║ 3      ║
║        ║   X    ║ null   ║ 5      ║
║   2    ║   Y    ║ null   ║ 1      ║
║        ║   Y    ║ AB     ║ 3      ║
║        ║   Y    ║ null   ║ 5      ║
╚════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

And would like to get following

```
╔════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ record ║ Brand  ║ Model  ║ Spec   ║
╠════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║   1    ║   X    ║ DF     ║ 1      ║
║        ║   X    ║ DF     ║ 3      ║
║        ║   X    ║ DF     ║ 5      ║
║   2    ║   Y    ║ AB     ║ 1      ║
║        ║   Y    ║ AB     ║ 3      ║
║        ║   Y    ║ AB     ║ 5      ║
╚════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

ie. I'm dreaming about something like 'fill up' analogue to the [fill down tutorial](http://kb.refinepro.com/2012/03/fill-down-right-and-secure-way.html)

I haven't found a functionality which covers that out of the box.
Do you have further information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try with this quick hack ?

(use Transform on your column "Model")

```
row.record.cells['Model'].value[0]
```

Here is the dataset I used

```
record,Brand,Model,Spec
1,X,,1
,X,DF,3
,X,,5
2,Y,,1
,Y,AB,3
,Y,,5
```

Demo

[image]

Comment: doesn't work -  Rows with null show following Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: @til I added a screencast and the dataset I used. Are you sure that your real data is the same as in your question ?

Comment: I'm working on UTF-8 data and had to adapt that before. Now it works - Thanks @Ettore